# Как узнать выбран ли какой-нибудь элемент в TListView?

Tags: delphi

Есть ли свойство у компонента ListView, которое позволяет узнать, выбран ли какой-нибудь элемент в этом списке?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228422/delphi-get-current-index-of-selected-item-in-tlistview - itemIndex

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо, проблема была решена. Может тогда еще подскажете, почему я не могу прописать свойство кнопки, которая находится в другой форме(vcl модуле соответственно), хотя в implementation модуль указан?

Comment: А вот это уже новый вопрос, и его так и нужно оформить. С дополнительной информацией.

Comment: @KoVadim Благодарю, этот вопрос закрыт